# Fiber of morphism induced by map on stalks

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Given a morphism of schemes $f\colon X\to Y$ and a point $x\in X$, the map on the stalks induces a morphism $\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \to \operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)} $. Is it true that the fiber of the latter morphism in $f(x)$ coincides with the fiber of $f$ in $f(x)$?

Using the language of algebra: Given a ring homomorphism $f\colon A\to B$ and a prime $\mathfrak{q}$ in $B$ and letting $\mathfrak{p}$ denote the inverse image of $\mathfrak{q}$ under $f$, is it true that $B_{\mathfrak{q}} \otimes_{A_{\mathfrak{p}}} A_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}A_{\mathfrak{p}} = B \otimes_A A_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}A_{\mathfrak{p}}$?

Comment: Phil has given an easy counterexample. But note that replacing $X$ by a neighborhood of $x$ won't change the map on stalks, whereas it may change the fiber of $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $A =\mathbb C$, $B = \mathbb C[x]$, and $\mathfrak q = (x)$.